# MySql Greater Than on String

Tags: mysql

I am wondering why when i run WHERE xyz < 5 where xyz is a string it still brings back results. Why or how can i make it so that if i search "greater than" or any math operation like > < <= >= on a string it just brings back zero results.

If a string is search using the math functions i want it to bring back zero results and im confused why it brings back results with "LKJLK" can't possibly be greater than anything because its not a number.  Shouldn't this return false.?? Thanks for any help.

Comment: When it comes to text values, "greater than" and "less than" mean "comes alphabetically after" and "comes alphabetically before".  That's pretty standard stuff in databases and pretty much any programming language.  If you don't want to compare strings with those operators then maybe you should just not compare strings with those operators.  Don't expect a database to read your mind; write code to do what you want to do and not do what you don't want to do.  If your code compares strings to numbers then it's bad code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that makes sense.  I am trying to create a global search button that searches on all of the columns but because some columns are string and some int.  I guess ill have to build a work around.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating an application with a MySQL back-end?  You can probably put logic into the application code to ensure that comparisons always use appropriate types.  You should certainly not preclude comparative searches on strings because it's quite legitimate to test whether the value in a text column is less than '5'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add an additional `WHERE` clause to ensure the value is a number. For example:

```
SELECT Data
  FROM table
  WHERE Data > 10
    AND Data REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$';
```

Here's a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/448937/3) showing it in action.

There are other ways to test if the value is a number. A search on SO will give you more than a few methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select
 USername
 from
 users
 where username>'     '
```

this will select the username from users where the user name is greater than 5 positions. is that what you were looking for?